# Can I use C++11 list-initializer syntax for vectors with variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some double variables: a, b,c...
I want to construct a vector v such as v[0]=a, v[1]=b etc
Can I do this with C++11 list initializer ? i.e this syntax :

```
std::vector<double> v{a,b,c};
```

If no, is there a way to do this directly, without multiple pushback() ?

Comment: @mdrlol It will work. No problem.

Comment: Did you mean to start with `v[0]=a`?

Comment: @Ninetainedo I didn't since I remember (maybe incorrectly) that it only work with constants

Comment: First thing to do before posting on SO would be to try it.

Comment: @Bastien: True, but that merely turns the question into "Is this legal C++11 or a compiler extension?".

Answer (score 0):

You can answer questions like this easily using this online C++ compiler: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

I tried this and it worked:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    double a{}, b{}, c{};
    std::vector<double> v{a,b,c};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A parody on the post of @Chris Guzak:)

I tried this and it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    double a = 1.1, b = 2.2, c = 3.3;

    std::vector<double> v { std::cref( a ), std::cref( b ), std::cref( c ) };

    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

One more parody.

Wow! I tried this and it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    double a = 1.1, b = 2.2, c = 3.3;

    std::vector<double> v;
    v.reserve( 3 );

    for ( auto x : { a, b, c } ) v.push_back( x );

    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And one more

I tried this and it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    double a = 1.1, b = 2.2, c = 3.3;

    std::vector<double> v;

    v.insert( v.end(), { a, b, c } );

    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Oh, and I tried this and it also worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    double a = 1.1, b = 2.2, c = 3.3;

    std::vector<double> v;

    v.assign( { a, b, c } );

    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

What else I did not try?:)